# Getting an "'App' is declared but its value is never read" error message on "App" of the index.tsx function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function

This is a React project using TypeScript. I'm attempting to learn how to use a modal window for a project I am working on. This method I've been using is from a YouTube tutorial which uses JavaScript as opposed to TypeScript on their React project.

Do you happen to know what the problem is? I am concerned about my folder structure and if the setup is incorrect at all. I am trying to complete this project using TypeScript.

At this point in the code, I should only be able to open the modal.

There is still more to complete but I want to get this working first before I continue!

Here is the folder structure:

[image: Here is the folder structure]

[Here is the link to the YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCvemsUfwPQ&t=917s&ab_channel=PedroTech)

- (I stopped at the 11:07 mark in the video)

**index.tsx:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Modal from "./components/Modal";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
     <h1>Hey, click on the button to open the modal.</h1>
        <button
          className="openModalBtn"
          onClick={() => {
            setOpenModal(true);
          }}
        >
          Open
        </button>
        {openModal && <Modal />}
     </div>
document.getElementById("root")
```

**Modal.tsx:**

```
import * as React from "react";

export default class Modal extends React.Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="modalBackground">
        <div className="modalContainer">
          <button> X </button>
          <div className="title">
            <h1>Are you sure you want to continue?</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="body">
            <p>
              The next page is awesome! You should move forward, you will enjoy
              it.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <button>Cancel</button>
            <button>Continue</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Cross Country Campground</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": false
  }
}
```

I'm just not exactly sure if my setup is correct since I am implementing TypeScript to this React project which is a first for me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with how you have used your App component and called `.render` function.

```
function App() {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  return(
 <div>
     <h1>Hey, click on the button to open the modal.</h1>
        <button
          className="openModalBtn"
          onClick={() => {
            setOpenModal(true);
          }}
        >
          Open
        </button>
        {openModal && <Modal />}
     </div>
  )
  }

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I checked the youtube link you've posted and they have linked [the github repo](https://github.com/machadop1407/React-Modal-Tutorial/tree/main) which you can use as a reference.

If your goal is to learn how to build a modal and not setting up your project using TS, I recommend using something like [vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) to generate the initial boiler plate code.

Comment: You learn _way more_  about your stack if you don't work off boilerplate / starter repos. Not against them in principle but I wouldn't dissuade someone from taking that approach to learning a new technology. Start from first principles and iterate.